# "Error while signing" during UWP App Publsih

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2019, signing, msix

for a few days now, "Error while signing" appears whenever I try to build my UWP app as a release via "Publish". Unfortunately, no further information is displayed.
I have already tried with a new certificate, a complete reinstallation of Visual Studio including the SDKs and even with a new and empty project the error occurs.

When I build the project without signing, no error occurs. However as signing is necessary for UWP, this is no option. Using the signtool.exe does not seem to have any effect (it does not sign the .msixbundle, neither does it return any error)

After building with Visual Studio, I have found the following log in the event viewer, but I am not sure whether it is related to this error:

```
AppInsightsEvent Name = vs/telemetry/internalfault
          Description = Exception in SessionChannel.EventProcessorChannel ProcessEvents Channel = eventProcessorChannel
     TelemetrySession = '0bd4d105-ba92-44c0-bcba-1e4c4d4d5789' Started = True OptIn=True IsInitialized = True Cloned = False
      WatsonEventType = VisualStudioNonFatalErrors2
             UTC time = 2020-03-06T18:08:54

 Exception:
 System.IO.FileNotFoundException
 The file or assembly "Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource, Version=1.1.28.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" or a dependecy of it was not found. 
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationInsights.Channel.UniversalTelemetryChannel.IsAvailable()
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.SessionChannel.AsimovAppInsightsClientWrapper.CreateAppInsightsChannel(TelemetryConfiguration config)
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.SessionChannel.BaseAppInsightsClientWrapper.Initialize(String sessionId, String userId)
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.SessionChannel.BaseAppInsightsSessionChannel.Start(String sessionId)
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.EventProcessorRouter.RouteEvent(TelemetryEvent telemetryEvent, String sessionId, Boolean isDropped)
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.EventProcessor.ProcessEvent(TelemetryEvent telemetryEvent)
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.SessionChannel.EventProcessorChannel.ProcessEvents()
WerReportAddDump PID=3108 MSBuild WerDumpTypeMiniDump
```

Does someone have/had the same problem and has any information about how to resolve this?

Greetings

Comment: When you right click on our app in Solution Explorer, and click on "Store" and then "Associate your app with the Store", and then click on "Next" a couple times, do you see that your app is already associated with the store?  If not, you don't have the needed certificate for signing for a "Publish" to the store.

Comment: Does this apply? [Update breaks Signtool](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/eab63276-5941-49b7-aac2-039e62288bde/kb4535996-for-windows-10-breaks-signtoolexe)?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Thinking of it again, I indeed ran an update that night. I'll try to uninstall this later..

Comment: @GregThatcher My app is sideloaded, the Store is not used.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT high chances this is the error. However I have trouble deinstalling the update.
I tried to uninstall it via System Control and cmd.
When using `wusa /uninstall /kb:4535996` I get Error Code 0x80070490: Element not found. So I downloaded the .msu and tried `wusa /uninstall <pathToMSU>`. This starts fine but still ends with the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not an expert but maybe it wasn't unstalled in the first place? Does Settings -> Update -> history tell you anything?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT I probably think, it was that I wiped the WU cache along with some other temporary files a few days ago, as I suspected an error there.
I just reseted Windows while keeping files and apps and this fixed it, as the mentioned Update was also removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also encountered the same problem a few days ago. After reverting the win10 version from 18363.693 to 18363.657, regenerating UWP did not cause the problem of being unable to sign again. Hope to solve the problem you encountered.

Comment: Thinking of it again, I indeed ran an update that night. I'll try to uninstall this later..